# I need support to add the AWS variables in Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

Need support to add following variables to my terraform code so that user can input the details and it can create the desired resources in AWS. I don't know how to do that your kind support will be highly appreciated.

`

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
      ami                    = "ami-0fe0b2cf0e1f25c8a"
      instance_type          = "t2.micro"
      vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
      subnet_id              = var.subnet_id
      key_name               = var.key
       }

variable "security_group_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "Enter the SG"
}
variable "key" {
  description = "Enter the Kaypair"
}
variable "subnet_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "Enter the Subnet"
}
```

`

How can i add following AWS variables
Size, AZ, HDD, Port

I have tried the following code.But due to lack of knowledge i dont know how to add the required variables e.g there are resources + data source.

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
      ami                    = "ami-0fe0b2cf0e1f25c8a"
      instance_type          = "t2.micro"
      vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
      subnet_id              = var.subnet_id
      key_name               = var.key
       }

variable "security_group_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "Enter the SG"
}
variable "key" {
  description = "Enter the Kaypair"
}
variable "subnet_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "Enter the Subnet"
}
```

Comment: to be honest, the query is not that clear 
do you want to know how to add [HDD](ebs_block_device {volume_size}), availability_zone  and other attributes.

May be few things would be already clear if you check the 

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance

Comment: Thanks @ishuar, i have created the block # Block for create EC2 Instance
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  count                  = var.instance_count
  ami                    = "ami-0fe0b2cf0e1f25c8a"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
  subnet_id              = var.subnet_id
  key_name               = var.key
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}-${count.index + 1}"
  }
} 
and then add the variables
variable "key" {
  description = "Enter the Kaypair"
}
and same as for others, but i am unable to now understand how to + others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Malik, hopefully, this will help you and give you a bit of an idea how to initiate your config.

https://github.com/ishuar/terraform-eks/blob/main/examples/private_cluster/eks-ec2-private-jump-host.tf#L253

this only includes basic configuration for EC2 Instances.

If you are looking for a module then its better to look into: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance

unfortunately, there are multiple ways of defining the resources that you have to add to your Ec2 instance but the very standard and basic way would be

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  count                  = var.instance_count
  ami                    = "ami-0fe0b2cf0e1f25c8a"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [var.security_group_id]
  subnet_id              = var.subnet_id
  key_name               = var.key
  tags                   = { Name = "${var.name}-${count.index + 1}" }

  ## For the root volume attached to Ec2 instance
  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = var.delete_on_termination
    encrypted             = var.encrypted
    iops                  = var.iops
    volume_size           = var.volume_size
    volume_type           = var.volume_type
    throughput            = var.throughput
  }
  ## For the additional EBS block device attached to Ec2 instance
  ebs_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = var.delete_on_termination
    device_name           = var.device_name
    encrypted             = var.encrypted
    iops                  = var.iops
    kms_key_id            = var.kms_key_id
    snapshot_id           = var.snapshot_id
    volume_size           = var.volume_size
    volume_type           = var.volume_type
    throughput            = var.throughput
  }
}
```

Regarding ports I assume you mean the ports to access, those can be controlled via security groups.
I hope this info somewhat helps even though it is not exactly a module of complete `aws_instance` resource somewhat you can have an idea.

Comment: Excellent Guru. Thank you so very much. really appreciated for your kind support.